# Sending messages to connected clients from server with websocket in AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I am really new to AWS and javascript, so please bear with me if I make any mistakes.

I am running my code inside a lambda function in AWS in Nodejs.12x environment. (Upto now I was able to successfully connect lambda and the client through websocket and pass messages from the client to the server (in lambda) from wsCat)

Now I want to send messages from the server to the connected cient with websocket.
I have seen that we can use the connection URL for this. Making a HTTP post to this URL will get it to work. (That is what it says in the docs)

I extracted the connectionId from the connect request but from there on I am clueless on what I should do next.

Can you please tell me how to make the server send messages to the client. The code to make that work will be really helpful

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway offers Websocket endpoints - you can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html

They have a code sample you can deploy here:
[https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:729047367331:applications~simple-websockets-chat-app](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:729047367331:applications%7Esimple-websockets-chat-app)